# Antiderivative exists but not integrable

Tags: real-analysis

In the sense of Riemann, could an integral (if there exists could you give the less pathological counter-example possible) have an antiderivative but not be integrable on a compact subset?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Let $f(x)=x^{1.2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x\in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. It is a differentiable function (check it) in the interval $[0,1]$ and its derivative equals to $f'(x)=1.2x^{0.2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{x^{0.8}}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x\ne 0$ and $f'(0)=0$. So obviously $f'$ has an antiderivative in $[0,1]$, but it isn't even bounded, hence not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Riemann integrable function has to be bounded in particular.

Comment: I don't understand. Take $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_\varepsilon ^1 f'(x)dx=\sin(1).$ This limit converges, and so the $f'(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: @Chickenmancer, maybe the improper integral converges. But there is a difference between Riemann integral and improper integral. A function which is not bounded can't be Riemann integrable.

Comment: I suppose I was thinking that the point $0$ was of measure $0$ and so wasn't worried about it fitting the actual definition :P. Thanks for clarifying.